# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype' in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
steps_per_epoch = int(BUFFER_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE)
hist = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=test_ds,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    verbose = 2
)
```

I'm getting the error as

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-76f73d918c4d> in <module>()
     13     epochs=EPOCHS,
     14     callbacks=callbacks,
---> 15     verbose = 2
     16 )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

AttributeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 947, in compute_loss  *
        return super().compute_loss(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss  **
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 199, in __call__
        y_t, y_p, sw = match_dtype_and_rank(y_t, y_p, sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 684, in match_dtype_and_rank
        if ((y_t.dtype.is_floating and y_p.dtype.is_floating) or

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I tried updating my TensorFlow, Keras, and python on collab still didn't help the situation.

What can be the possible solution to this problem?

Comment: It's because one of your `model.fit` arguments (train_ds, test_ds, callbacks) has `None` value. You should try printing them out to see which one. Once you find out, could you post the code where that argument value is assigned?

Comment: @taxevader 

train:  ({'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(224, 59), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(224, 59), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)}, TensorSpec(shape=(224, 59), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))

test:  <BatchDataset element_spec=({'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(224, 59), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(224, 59), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)}, TensorSpec(shape=(224, 59), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))>

callbacks:  [<keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping object at 0x7f82db4cfad0>]

This is the output I got! How do I drop name here?

Comment: Anonymous! Have you found the solution? I am facing the same issue. Your help will be highly appreciated.